# Touchégg doesn't work on my Chromebook

Tags: touchpad, chromebook

I have an HP Chromebook 14. I erased ChromeOS and replaced it with Elementary OS. It has all the proper drivers for the touchpad and such.

I installed Touchégg and ran it in a terminal. It said any gestures recognised would in the terminal. The problem is, nothing showed up. I just want some three finger guestures of opening the workspace switcher and moving between workspaces. Any help?

Comment: Expect these problems from a Chromebook because they are made for chrome OS

Answer (score 1):

Touchegg is made for synaptic driver for
touchpads.  Loki uses libinput instead. There is a project https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput gestures

I haven't tried it. I just installed synaptics drive and used it with xSwipe but it should work with Touchegg too. If libinput gestures doesn't work for you.  Let me know.  I kept notes on how I set up xSwipe for multi touch gestures and will gladly share them if you want.