# Touchpad not working on HP chromebook 14

Tags: release-freya, hp, chromebook, touchpad

I have removed chrome OS and the bios that comes with Chromebooks and replaced it with SeaBIOS with elementary OS installed. It works very well, but I can't seem to get the touchpad working.

I have spent a while looking at countless posts and forums trying to find solutions from people who had similar problems, and have tried various suggestions. All of this with no luck.

Using the command

> cat /proc/bus/input/devices

Used to at least show my touchpad (which, according to it, is a Cypress APA touchpad) but it appears I have done something in the process of trying solutions to cause this to stop.

I have been using a Microsoft PS/2 mouse instead

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Related, though slightly different? http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/4368/5565